# Need help in mysql database backup on Windows except mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, windows

Can anyone tell me what is the easy way to backup 500Gb datasize on **windows** environment ? My physical memory is 672 GB RAM on server?
Which tools will be fast to back up and restore?
Note : mysqldump will take more than 1 week for 500GB datasize 
Any suggestion with details and is there way any way around that it can take within 2 days?

Comment: Do you have slave and not used for production purpose?

Comment: No , I dont have slave server . This is the production server @Mannoj

Comment: @McDonalds I'm not understanding what u r suggested me. Can you please tell me details , do we have any tools or is there any workaround ?

Comment: out of 500Gb , weekly the data will truncate and add same millions of rows, there are three tables which weekly used for transaction. combined them , there are 200 Gb which changes regularly every month.                   My server is : windows 2012 server R2                                                                Intel Xeon Cpu 2 GHZ ( 2 processor) 672 Installed physically RAM  @McDonald's

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html ? mysqldump is just one (bad) way to do a backup.

Comment: i read the documentation, i wud happy if i get any free backup tools for backup and restore ,time consumption would be reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may give it a try using percona backup alpha version for Windows - [Download_Link](https://www.percona.com/downloads/XtraBackup/XtraBackup-1.6/Windows-alpha/)
.

Below are the steps after installation in Windows Bash.

```
C:\Users\lorainne>bash

C:\Users\lorainne$ xtrabackup –user=root –password=secret -host=127.0.0.1 –port=3306 –backup –target-dir=\test
```

I haven't tested this but this seems to be a working command, ensure that you have https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes - Build 14332 fixed to have prctl system call supported on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @Mannoj , Can you please tell me what are the steps to take backup using xtrabackup on windows environment after installation of backup alpha version?

Comment: try executing the above commands. You may verify the commands using xtrabackup --help.

Comment: Thanks @Mannoj , do u have any idea how much time will take for 200 Gb database backup using xtrabackup

Comment: Depends upon ur free space in ram, cpu processing capacity, IO read/write capacity if not you may take once and see how long it takes and start keeping your bench mark. But it can't take more than 10hrs in decent provisioned servers. First time I'm hearing 672GB RAM. I hope your config and server capacity should be more. Check the IOPs and CPU and run it on non-peak hrs.

Comment: Yes its 672 GB RAM, normally IO read/write capacity good.@Mannoj